# Unexpected behavior of DateTimeFormatter of Joda Time?

Tags: java, jodatime

I was expecting the DateTimeFormatter to return null or nothing if its method 'public String print(ReadableInstant instant)' is passed a null DateTime (which is also a ReadableInstant.)

Surprisingly it returns the current time instead of throwing an error. Could this be a bug ?

Here is the related code -

```
import org.joda.time.*;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class JodaTest {

public static void main(String[]args){

    DateTime dt = null;
    String ss = getTimeInAFormat(dt);
    System.out.println(ss);


}

public static String getTimeInAFormat(DateTime time) {

    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM-dd-YYYY hh:mm");
    String dateTime = dtf.print(time); // Should throw an error or return,  
    return dateTime; // a String = "NO DATE SET"

}


}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It behaves as [documented](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#print%28org.joda.time.ReadableInstant%29):

> Parameters:
>
> instant - instant to format, null means now

Comment: ok. i get it. but i am surprised to see why the developer would want to provide a non-null output anyway. maybe just to save the time taken to create a DateTime and then pass it to the print method.